# Придумать параметрическое уравнение поверхности

Tags: математика, формулы

Вот эти кривые в 2д получаться движением окружности по окружности.
[image: рис. 1]

А вот эти получаться движением сферы по сфере(по идее).

[image: рис. 2]

Как получать координаты точки на такой поверхности от двух параметров?
Например t0 и t1 каждый от 0 до 1  позволяют получить любую точку на поверхности.
Также  важно чтобы можно было задавать форму поверхности изменяя радиусы обеих или малой сферы. Если можно и сделать чтобы задавать количество этих “капель”.

Задавал такой же вопрос на ENG ...но никто ничего не понял. Что тут непонятного?
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280969/invent-parametric-equation-of-the-surface

По поводу форума:
Поиск меток странный… где метки: параметрическое  уравнение, surface, поверхность, equation…Почему нельзя отправить личное сообщение тем кому что то непонятно 
“put on hold as unclear what you're asking by…” ?

Comment: Таких меток нет потому, что у нас тут онтопик — это программирование, а не математика. А ваши метки относятся к математике. А личные сообщения нельзя направлять именно для того, чтобы авторы вопросов не надоедали авторам ответов просьбами о консультациях по смежным темам.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится к программированию

Comment: Пф…ну так это будет прога .
Нужно сначала придумать простой алгоритм расчета возвращающий точку на  похожей поверхности. Теперь относиться ко всем языкам сразу? =).